# Best way to filter out reponse from Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

I'm struggling to find out the best way to filter out the response JSON from Elastic Search search query, I know two of them, they are as follows:

- filter_path: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering
- _source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/run-a-search.html#source-filtering

I can't decide which one to use, what effect they'll be having on the query, performance, and other aspects.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_path` is somewhat of a superset of `_source`. It enables you to get rid of the response metadata while `_source` is limited to the docs' actual source.

Exempli gratia:
`?filter_path=hits.hits._source.id` is similar to `?_source=id` but the former will result in

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "O1819976"
        }
      },
      ...
```

while the latter contains all the common details:

```
{
  "took" : 39,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 11,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "O1819976",
        "_score" : null,
        "_ignored" : [
          ...
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "O1819976"       <----
        }
      },
```

Neither of them affects the query performance since they're applied after the search phase.

I suppose `filter_path` could be slightly faster at the end b/c there are fewer JSON bytes to transfer over the network.

Comment: In order to add to @joe's answer, there's a third possibility using [`docvalue_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-docvalue-fields) instead of source filtering (for any field types except `text`). Field data is retrieved from doc values per field instead of loading the whole `_source` document and filtering it. That's what Kibana does!

Comment: And a fourth way is by using [stored fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/run-a-search.html#stored-fields)